# High order function in express middleware

Tags: javascript, express

Can't send params to a high order function in JS. The function it's not getting req and res args

```
// In router.js

const { getAll } = require('./controller')
router.get('/coordinadores', getAll()('mentor'))

// In controller.js

exports.getAll = (req, res) => {
  return (role) => {
    var filter = { role }
    if (req.user.role == 'mentor') filter = { role, centro: { "$in": req.user.centro } }
    Model.find(filter, '-password -role -__v -createdAt -updatedAt -centro').lean().exec()
      .then(list => { res.status(200).json({ list }) })
      .catch(err => { errorHandler(req, res, err) })
  }
}

// Result
// TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
router.get('/coordinadores', getAll()('mentor'))
```

you're calling `getAll` without any arguments. To create a HoF you should create it like this

```
const getAll = role => (req, res) => {
  // your code 
}
```

and then

```
router.get('/coordinadores', getAll('mentor'))
```

this will call the `getAll` function with `mentor` and it will return a function reference that will be called with `req` and `res` by express

Comment: however note, `role` is not available on `req` object

Answer (score 0):

For an alternate, `express` way is to pass values through `middleware` like:

```
function setDefaultRole((req, res, next) => {
  if (not some check here) {
    // if check fails, setting default role
    req.user.role = 'mentor'
  }
  // call the next middleware
  next();
})

function getAll((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.user.role == 'mentor') {
    // continue logic
    filter = ???
  }
})
```